# block view is not displaying

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming

This problem starts with the subtheme. I am using drupal 7 with a subtheme based on omega 3.1.

For some reason node title and admin tabs are displaying only on the home page and two basic pages, while they do not appear on the rest of the website(articles, basic pages, custom type content).

I tried goggling and trying out different solutions but none of them were successful.

So I thought I could create a view block that would display only a node title. in the view I used contextual filters 'content: Nid', display 1 item, fields 'content: title'. By default auto preview does not display anything, when you insert a node number or a page name it displays it's title which means that the view works fine(as example when I enter '1' it displays 'About me' title).

After that I insert the block on a page by going blocks > configure for the block view > selecting the region in the sub theme I am using and in Show block on specific pages selecting 'Only the listed pages' and typing '1' as an example.

When I click save block and going to about me page I still do not see the title then check by inspect the page there is no html for the block view found.

To check weather the problem is not in the omega, I switch to bartik and select to display the block for bartik theme too, but still cannot see it on the page. The answer is probably something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have the 'Only listed pages' setting wrong.
I tend to use pathauto, so always have nice 'friendly' URL's, but I suspect you want "node/1" rather than simply "1" in the "only listed pages" field of the block config.

WRT your initial issue - are you using Delta? Regions may not be enabled for all delta's of the subtheme which could cause the initial problem.